# Could not load file or assembly error at runtime after removing Autofac but works fine with Assembly.Load('"MyCompany.MyAdaptoer")

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, autofac

We were using Autofac with the windows service project and everything was working fine.
The main project was loading another assembly using `Assembly.Load("XYZAssembly")` where XYZAssembly is another project in the solution and it was also referenced in the main project.

Now due to some reason I removed Autofac and Assembly.Load() and the project build successfully. But when any method of the XYZAssembly is called I get the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'SVI.DYNAMITE.XYZAssembly, Version=1.1.17122.13, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Now if we call `Assembly.Load("XYZAssembly")` everything works fine. But if this is not called than I get the above error at runtime.

P.S: I have made sure that XYZAssembly is built successfully and file is created in bin folder of main project. I have also tried referencing the DLL file rather than referencing the project.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just to help narrow things down - this is definitely an assembly loading problem, not an Autofac problem. Focus your troubleshooting on the assembly loading part.

Comment: Thanks @TravisIllig I am looking out on the same side but I initially thought that maybe autofac did some configuration that makes the assemblies work only when they are dynamically loaded.

Comment: Nope. Autofac doesn't do anything with assembly loading. That's all framework.